# Use javascript delay with document.write

Tags: javascript, function, delay

Can someone help me to input a javascript delay to this code.
I want to make this code to open after 2 sec. when you open the url.
Rest of the site load normaly.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var avail=$z:value[article.availableinstock];

if ($z:value[article.availableinstock] < 1)
{
document.write('<div class="shop_not">');
document.write("In order!");
}
else if ($z:value[article.availableinstock] >=100)
{
document.write('<div class="shop_ok">');
document.write(" 100+ in stock" );
}
else if ($z:value[article.availableinstock] >=50 )
{
document.write('<div class="shop_ok">');
document.write(" 50+ in stock" );
}
else if ($z:value[article.availableinstock] >=25 )
{
document.write('<div class="shop_ok">');
document.write(" 25+ in stock" );
}
else
{
document.write('<div class="shop_bob">');
document.write(+ avail.toFixed(0));
document.write(" in stock" );
}
</script>
```

Comment: why do you want to wait 2 seconds?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice

Comment: The reason to use ex. 2 sec is that the articlelist is so slow when i use the script, even only the value.

Comment: So it would be better to make the articlelist *fast* than adding 2 sec delay (what every user will notice)? Or putting the javascript in a *callback* of the articlelist instead of hoping everything is done within two sec?

Comment: i see your point Dominik! The page is fast "enough", but it is this script that makes it slow, because the article.available query required so much. So my plan was that after the page was loaded then this script will load.

Comment: But couldn't you optimize your script to make it faster? (i.e. use your `avail`-variable in the `if`-conditions instead of querying 5 times). Other point: if you use jQuery (or something similar) you could use the `.ready()` handler to call your script after the rest is done.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to put everything in a `setTimeout(function() {... your stuff ...}, 2000)` call.

This should look like:

```javascript
function yourStuff() {
  var avail=$z:value[article.availableinstock];

  if ($z:value[article.availableinstock] < 1) {
    document.write('<div class="shop_not">');
    document.write("In order!");
  } else if ($z:value[article.availableinstock] >=100) {
    document.write('<div class="shop_ok">');
    document.write(" 100+ in stock" );
  } else if ($z:value[article.availableinstock] >=50 ) {
    document.write('<div class="shop_ok">');
    document.write(" 50+ in stock" );
  } else if ($z:value[article.availableinstock] >=25 ) {
    document.write('<div class="shop_ok">');
    document.write(" 25+ in stock" );
  } else {
    document.write('<div class="shop_bob">');
    document.write(+ avail.toFixed(0));
    document.write(" in stock" );
  }
}
```

Then, somewhere inside your page `body` you simply call

```html
<script type="text/javascript">setTimeout(yourStuff, 2000);</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Enclose you code in a function and use `setTimeout` JS function.

```
function function_name () {
    var avail=$z:value[article.availableinstock];

    if ($z:value[article.availableinstock] < 1)
    {
        document.write('<div class="shop_not">');
        document.write("In order!");
    }
    else if ($z:value[article.availableinstock] >=100)
    {
        document.write('<div class="shop_ok">');
        document.write(" 100+ in stock" );
    }
    else if ($z:value[article.availableinstock] >=50 )
    {
        document.write('<div class="shop_ok">');
        document.write(" 50+ in stock" );
    }
    else if ($z:value[article.availableinstock] >=25 )
    {
        document.write('<div class="shop_ok">');
        document.write(" 25+ in stock" );
    }
    else
    {
        document.write('<div class="shop_bob">');
        document.write(+ avail.toFixed(0));
        document.write(" in stock" );
    }
}

setTimeout('function_name()', 2000);
```